# Matploblib colorbar not using the correct colormap in networkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

While trying to use a given colormap in NetworkX graph drawing, seems Matplotlib `colorbar()` completely ignores my defined colormap and use `viridis` instead.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import itertools

# Graph size
m = 5

# Create a random weights
weights = [ ((i, j), 2*np.random.random()-1) for i, j in itertools.product(np.arange(m), np.arange(m))]

# Create graph and set weights
G = nx.complete_graph(m)
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, dict(weights), 'weight')
edgelist, edge_color = zip(*nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight').items())

# Draw graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color='#aaaaaa', axes=ax)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=edgelist, edge_color=edge_color, edge_cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, axes=ax)
cb = plt.colorbar(edges, ax=ax)
plt.axis('off')
print(cb.cmap.name)
```

The `print` output shows `viridis`, but I'd expect `coolwarm` as defined.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (bug perhaps), the `cmap`  returned by `nx.draw_networkx_edges` is set to `viridis` instead the one set in function call. Hence after the call to `draw_networkx_edges` I have set:

```
edges.cmap = plt.cmap.coolwarm
edges.set_clim(np.min(edge_color),np.max(edge_color))
```

And that works.

For sake of documentation NetworkX version is `2.4`. Stable in October, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! This worked for me.  In my case the colormap was returned as "grey" when I had set to "edge_cmap=plt.cm.jet".  The color on the edges themselves was fine, but the colorbar was not correct.  A correction from above I would note is to set...

> edges.cmap = plt.cm.coolwarm

In my case, the "set_clim" was not necessary as I had used edge_vmin and edge_vmax attributes when defining draw_networkx_edges.